# Store list of git branches in variable

Tags: javascript, git, visual-studio-code

I am trying to put all my branches in a list using `git branch`. I was thinking like

```
    const branches = executecommand('git branch -l')
```

but I don't know the right way to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+execute+command

Answer (score 1):

I think the `child_process` module in Node core is what you want:

```
const cp = require('child_process')

const branches = cp.execSync('git branch -l')
```

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Answer (score 0):

To adress only the git part of the question, even if it might not be the main focus, the `-l` flag is useless here, since it is implied as long as no explicit references are passed.

However, depending on the level of exhaustivity you need, you might consider using `-a` to list *all* branches, not only local ones.

Comment: Although it is frowned upon as improductive type of comment, I have to say your explicit thankfulness at least sounds genuine and is heartwarming ;-) *De rien...*

Comment: It may be an improductive type of comment but I truly wish you everything you want in this beautiful life and I am grateful for your help